# Scraping a webpage with Python

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to learn to scrape webpage (http://www.expressobeans.com/public/detail.php/185246), however I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  I think it's to do with identifing the xpath but how do I get the correct path (if that is the issue)?  I've tried Firebug in Firefox as well as the Developer Tools in Chrome.

I want to be able to scrape the Manufacturer value (D&L Screenprinting) as well as all the Edition Details.

python script:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.expressobeans.com/public/detail.php/185246')

tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

buyers = tree.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/dl/dd[3]')

print buyers
```

returns:

```
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

remove tbody from the xpath

```
buyers = tree.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tr[2]/td/table/tr/td[1]/dl/dd[3]')
```

Comment: That returns [<Element dd at 0x10aae93c0>]

Comment: its a list containing an 'lxml.html.HtmlElement' - use buyers[0].text_content()

Comment: From that, is it possible to return a value for a specific key? E.g currently that outputs 'Year:2014Class:CinemaStatus:OfficialReleased:01/16/14Run:185Technique:Screen PrintSize:18 X 24Markings:Numbered' but if I only want to return '2014' or 'Numbered' for example?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by suggesting you look at the page HTML and try to find a node closer to the value you are looking for, and build your path from there to make it shorter and easier to follow.

In that page I can see that there is a "dl" with class "itemListingInfo" and under that one all the information you are looking for.

Also, if you want the "D&L Screenprinting" text, you need to extract the text from the link.

Try with this modified version, it should be straightforward to add the other xpath expressions and get the other fields as well.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.expressobeans.com/public/detail.php/185246')

tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

buyers = tree.xpath('//dl[@class="itemListingInfo"]/dd[2]/a/text()')

print buyers
```

Comment: I would have thought '//dl[@class="itemListingInfo"]/dd[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]' would return 'Year' but it returned '[ ]' . Why's that wrong? Also, for each <tr> in the <tbody> how would I add the first <td> values into a dictionary as the keys with the following <td> values as the values? e.g [Year, 2014], [Class, Cinema], [Status, Official]...?

Comment: You need to remove the "tbody" from the path, and also add "/text()" at the end to get the actual text. Try with this one: '//dl[@class="itemListingInfo"]/dd[3]/table/tr[1]/td[1]/text()'. Also, I think you should add a separate question regarding how to put everything in a dictionary as it'd be difficult for me to write code in this comment section.